# Twitter api text field value is truncated

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, twitter

why text field value is truncated and how can i get complete value.
As of now i am trying to get text field value like below

```
do {
       if let responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject],
           arrayStatuses = responseObject["statuses"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
               let arrTweets:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
               for status in arrayStatuses {
                   let text = status["text"]!
                   print(status["text"]!)
               }
       }
}
```

**output is**

RT @WarfareWW: #Russia/#India may hold launches of BrahMos cruise missiles from Su-30MKI vs sea/grnd trgts at the end of this year https://…

three dots at the end of line. i need to print complete text without truncation.

Twitter sample search result JSON Data

```
{
      "created_at": "Mon Aug 01 08:07:43 +0000 2016",
      "id": 760024194079916032,
      "id_str": "760024194079916032",
      "text": "RT @khalidasopore: #KEXIT #KASHEXIT #KashmirKillings #Inida #Pakistan Just trend it my dear Indians to save #Kashmir from Pak Goons https:/…",
      "truncated": false
}
```

Comment: can you proof us that you are getting correct string as a response, show that request response in web or something

Comment: `UILabel`s will truncate text if they are a fixed height and width, you may also need to set `label.numberOfLines = 0` - Otherwise following @Lu_'s comment can you provide a json example.

Comment: it's not just a issue of UILabel even print() does truncate string

Comment: provide us some proof of that, show json in web or something, it is not normal that saving to variable is turncating string

Comment: to be specific it's twitter hastag search api response, updated my question with json

Answer (score 194, accepted):

The Twitter API has been changed recently, to support new rules regarding the 280 characters limit.

1. To get the full text of the tweet, add parameter `tweet_mode` with value `extended` to your request parameters.
2. Field `text` in the JSON response has been replaced by `full_text`

More info here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets

Comment: In a Java Spark Streaming application, where would I set the `tweet_mode` parameters? I have a `FilterQuery` which works with a listener.
@Ely

Comment: Not sure why Twitter doesn't include this in their official API documentation.  Thank goodness for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This helped, I am getting the full_text attribute back, but its still cutting off at around 210 characters for me.

Comment: It is ridiculous that the official documentation is outdated like this. Who updates their API docs with a "blog post"?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to implement spam filter functionality for the Twitter bot and drilled down to the fact that I am not getting the entire text response from Twitter API. Implementing this has made everything work.

Answer (score 34):

The status in this example is a retweet, and the text for retweets will be truncated to 140 characters even after including `tweet_mode=extended`. The full text of the original tweet is in the `retweeted_status` field of the JSON response. Here's what you want:

`let text = status["retweeted_status"]["full_text"]`.

Keep in mind that you should still include `tweet_mode=extended` in your request.

Comment: Retweets are still truncated today, however, if you include `expansions=referenced_tweets.id` in your API call it can give you the id of the original tweet to lookup directly, which will give you the full tweet text under `text`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
 tweets = api.search_tweets(q=search_term, tweet_mode='extended', count=tweet_amount)

for tweet in tweets:
    # check if the tweet is a retweet
    if tweet.full_text.startswith('RT @'):
    # if the tweet is a retweet, use the retweeted_status attribute
        full_text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
    else:
        full_text = tweet.full_text
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).