# Twitter streaming API not return full tweets

Tags: tweepy, tweets

I used tweepy to write the code to streaming tweets, but it seems the tweets were truncated and the long tweets I got are not full, they are end with ...

Is there any way that I could streaming the full long tweets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter search api text field value is truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717816/twitter-search-api-text-field-value-is-truncated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this parameter to your request: `tweet_mode=extended`
When parsing each tweet, use `full_text` instead of `text`.

It's documented here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates.html

Comment: But I try it on my code, it shows 'NameError: name 'extended' is not defined'. And from the document, I found 'extended' seems only work for the rest API, but I am using Streaming API

Comment: And I read the tweet json format carefully, I found most of the tweets have 'full_text' in  the 'extended_tweet'. However, the 'extended_tweet' sometimes in the  'retweeted_status', sometimes not. It's kind of confusing, I am not sure whether the text in 'full_text' equal to the 'text' wherever the 'full_text' is

Comment: You will need to check if the tweet is a retweet. If it is, use the retweet's full_text. If it is not, use the tweet's full_text.