# Python Tweepy 280 Character Statuses

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to scrape the full 280 character tweets off of twitter but I can't get them to not trail off with '...' after 140 chars. Here's my code:

```
import tweepy
import datetime

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("", "")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

end_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=0)
for status in api.user_timeline(targer_user):
    print(status.text)
    if status.created_at > end_date:
        break
```

I've read that adding `text_mode=extended`to the function will solve this, but it's making no difference for me. If I use another suggested argument `tweet_mode='extended'`, `text` is no longer an attribute of `status`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use `full_text` now to get the 280 char tweet. Try something along the lines of:

```
print(status.extended_tweet['full_text'])
```

The `tweet_mode='extended'` can be used in `user_timeline` if you want, in which case you would just use below:

```
print(status.full_text)
```

This looks a bit nicer to me.

It might also be worth pointing out that - from what I've read -  this might not work for a retweet ([Twitter streaming API not return full tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211501/twitter-streaming-api-not-return-full-tweets/47214802#47214802)) but there are separate bits of the api you can use for that, so be sure to check before you print.

Twitter docs, in case you want a closer look at the update: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates.html